# partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to import pandas modules, I imported california housing datasets and I want to get frame info but I get this error:

```
partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

what am I missing?
this is my code:

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import numpy as np
     from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
     from sklearn import linear_model
     from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
     from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
     chousing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)
     chousing.frame.info()
```

Comment: Try `import pandas` before any `sklearn` imports?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
import pandas as pd
```

or simply :

```
import pandas
```